# retrive properties bag of Webapplication JSOM

Tags: web-application, managed-property

i need to get the properties bag values of the current web application using JSOM
i succeeded to get the sites one but no way for the WebApp. to this [article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194716/get-value-of-property-bag-with-jsom)

any idea how can i retrive those values using JSOM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get properties bag values of current web application using JSOM. You have to some customized solution to get it.

There is one solution though but required http handlers, refer below links

https://chuvash.eu/2012/06/19/web-application-properties-as-json/

[How to access a Web application/Farm level property bag via jQuery/Javascript/ClientContext](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36945/how-to-access-a-web-application-farm-level-property-bag-via-jquery-javascript-cl)

Comment: I see, my prblem here that i need to get those properties using JS only , no webservices !

Comment: i followed this article and it works :https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/creating-generic-httphandler-in-sharepoint/